# How to debug ajax django view function which doesn't work in production only

Tags: python, ajax, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

How to debug such big peace of code which works localy and doesn't work in production considering the fact this is ajax function covered by djangorestfranewokr decorator - debugging doesn't work, django doesn't log any error, the only info I have when something gets broken is just 500. Or Django has to log errors, and something is wrong ?

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def load_dialog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        party_id = request.data['party_id']
        ticket_id = request.data['ticket_id']
        party = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=party_id)
        ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)
        try:
            dialog = Dialog.objects.get(Q(sales=party) | Q(sales=request.user.userprofile))
        except Dialog.DoesNotExist:
            dialog = None
        if dialog:
            textbool = None
            if dialog.sales == request.user.userprofile:
                textbool = "show"
            messages = Message.objects.filter(dialog=dialog)

            s_messages = serializers.serialize('json', messages)
            s_textbool = json.dumps(textbool)
            s_dialog_id = json.dumps(dialog.id)
            data = {
               'messages': s_messages,
               'sales': s_textbool,
               'dialog_id':s_dialog_id,
            }
        else:
            owner = ticket.ownership
            new_dialog = Dialog.objects.create(buyer=request.user.userprofile,sales=owner,ticket=ticket)
            textbool = None
            if new_dialog.sales == request.user.userprofile:
                textbool = "show"
            messages = Message.objects.filter(dialog=new_dialog)
            s_messages = serializers.serialize('json', messages)
            s_textbool = json.dumps(textbool)
            s_dialog_id = json.dumps(new_dialog.id)
            data = {
               'messages': s_messages,
               'sales': s_textbool,
               'dialog_id':s_dialog_id,
            }
    else:
        error = "Fuck"
        return error
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: If things are originating from an ajax call, perhaps the browser's console might produce an error message.

Comment: @MattCremeens 500, 403, 200 doesn't provide info to debug

Comment: Maybe add your `urls.py` that dispatches this particular request.

Comment: @MattCremeens url(r'^load_dialog/$', views.load_dialog),

Comment: 500 error means code error. Aren't you getting anything in the terminal?

Comment: @Exprator that is an exact problem. django doesn't log error to terminal , when it's ajax function

Comment: Why dont you log it to error.log , you will find code how to log code to file

Comment: @Exprator I fear it's not clear. It doesn't log to the terminal locally either .

Comment: I'm wondering if you should try using `filter` instead of `get` for `dialog` as it appears as though there is a chance of returning multiple records there.

Comment: @Exprator I know that in production almost only logging to file is possible

Comment: Do one thing. The else part is having a create query. Can you pass data like that so the else part works and create a row. So that you can debug it might be the problem in if part. Or else put print something after each line so that you can understand which line doesn't execute and skips

Comment: @Exprator I get it, but setting fre  print lines logging to file in logs is verry bad and hard approach. I'll spent lots of time testing it in production and even if I get the wrong line, I wouldn't know why its wrong.

Comment: @Exprator  and basically it's  not a solution. I d like to undestand why doesn't django log now locally at least for ajax func

Comment: You can check in the terminal for the print statements

Comment: @Exprator function works locally, in production it doesnt print to terminal, so I would need to set seperate log file where print function would also output

Comment: One thing. Is your debug on in production? Just to be sure. Maybe its false thus you can't see it in the terminal

Comment: @Exprator debug is on.

Comment: In chrome's dev toolbar put a breakpoint in your script and debug from there, that's the only way you can debug ajax

Answer (score 0):

In production you can use the [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#admins) settings to enable [Error Reporting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/error-reporting/) by email.

Comment: thanks, but do you know how to enable error tracking by django on just that peace of code, or at least the reason why it doesn't track them

Comment: You should get the full stacktrace with the exception that caused the error 500 in the mail.